# Can we make `__getattribute__` a descriptior (in any usable/meaningful way)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, propertydescriptor

How can we make code like the following emulate the `__getattribute__` method inherited from `object`? I really want to modify the behavior of `__getattribute__` but I'd like to begin by just getting the natural behavior.

```
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(*args):
        pass
   def __set__(*args)
       pass

class K:
    __getattribute__ = Descriptor()
```

Comment: Any `__getattribute__` you're ever likely to see is *already* a descriptor. It's impossible for `__getattribute__` to access `self` without being a descriptor.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can  make `__getattribute__` a descriptor! First of all, if a there is an integer member variable named `x`, then a descriptor `__get__` method written for `x` should return an integer. Likewise, since `__getattribute__` is a function, the `__get__` for `__getattribute__` will return a function. Initially, let's have `__get__` return a silly function named `foo`, just so that we can run the program see what's going on:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(*args):
        print("ENTERING __get__")
        print("Type(arg) for args passed into __get__:  ", end="")
        print(", ".join(map(lambda x: type(x).__name__, args)))
        def foo(*args):
            print("ENTERING `foo`")
            print("args passed into foo:  ", end="")
            print(", ".join(repr(arg) for arg in args))
            print("LEAVING `foo`")
            return "I AM THE RETURN VALUE OF FOO"
        return foo

class K:
    __getattribute__ = Descriptor()
```

Now, we try the following:

```
instance = K()
x = instance.x
```

Below are the statements seen on the the console (`stdout`):

```
ENTERING __get__
Type(arg) for args passed into __get__:  Descriptor, K, type
ENTERING `foo`
args passed into foo:  'x'
LEAVING `foo`
```

Note that `foo` doesn't receive the instance object through the usual `self` parameter. Instead, `foo` receives **ONLY** the attribute name `'x'`

Normally, the following two pieces of code produce the same end results:

```
x = instance.x
x = K.__getattribute__(instance, 'x')
```

Let's try running `K.__getattribute__(instance, 'x')`:

```
ENTERING __get__
Type(arg) for args passed into __get__:  Descriptor, NoneType, type
ENTERING `foo`
args passed into foo:  <__main__.K object at 0x01AFE0B8>, 'x'
LEAVING `foo`
```

The input to `__get__` and the input to `foo` are actually different from before.

```
+---------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| instance.x          | __get__(                    |  foo(<<string `x`>>)       |
|                     |   <<descriptor instance>>,  |                            |
|                     |   <<instance of K class>>,  |                            |
|                     |   <<K class itself>>        |                            |
|                     | )                           |                            |
+---------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| K.__getattribute__( | __get__(                    | foo(                       |
|    instance, 'x'    |    <<descriptor instance>>, |    <<instance of K class>>,|
| )                   |    <<None>>,                |    <<string `x`>>          |
|                     |    <<K class itself>>,      |                            |
|                     |                             |                            |
+---------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

As such, we want `__get__` to look like the following:

```
def __get__(descriptor, Kinstance, Kclass):
    if Kinstance:
        """
        return a function, `f`, which accepts as its only input
        the string name of an attribute.

           leftChild = f('leftChild')

        `f` is supposed to return that attribute 
        """
    else:  # Kinstance == None
        """
        return a function, `f`, which accepts as input two items:
        1) instance of some class
        2)the string name of an attribute.

           inst = Klass()
           leftChild = f(inst, 'leftChild')

        `f` is supposed to return that attribute 
        """
```

If you want the default behavior of `__getattribute__`, the following *almost* works:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __get__(descriptor, self, cls):
        if self:
            lamby = lambda attrname:\
                object.__getattribute__(self, attrname)
            return lamby
        else: # self == None
            return object.__getattribute__

class K:
    __getattribute__ = Descriptor()
```

### The Problem of Global Variables

Having `self` be a global variable inside of the lambda function named `lamby` is extremely dangerous.
When the lambda function eventually gets called, `self` won't be the same `self` that existed when the lambda function was defined. Consider the following example:

```
color = "white"

get_fleece_color = lambda shoop:\
    shoop + ", whose fleece was as " + color + " as snow."
```

`color` is a member variable inside of the lambda function `get_fleece_color`. When `get_fleece_color` was defined `color` was `"white"`, but that might change:

```
print(get_fleece_color("Igor"))

# [... many lines of code later...]

color = "pink polka-dotted"
print(get_fleece_color("Igor's cousin, 3 times removed"))
```

The output is:

```
Igor, whose fleece was white as snow.
Igor's cousin, 3 times removed Igor, whose fleece was as pink polka-dotted as snow.
```

Functions make with the `def` keyword instead of `lambda` are equally dangerous.

```
lamby = lambda attrname:\
    object.__getattribute__(self, attrname)

def lamby(attrname):
    object.__getattribute__(self, attrname)
```

We want to use `self` as it existed at the same time `lamby` was defined, and not use teh `self` values which exists when `lamby` is called. There are several ways to do this, 3 of which are shown below:

#### Avoid Global Variable Solution 1

```
lamby = lambda attrname, *, self=self:\
    object.__getattribute__(self, attrname)
```

#### Avoid Global Variable Solution 2

```
class Descriptor:
def __get__(descriptor, self, cls):
    lamby = object.__getattribute__
    if self: # self != None
        Method = type(descriptor.__get__)
        lamby = Method(object.__getattribute__, self)
    return lamby
```

#### Avoid Global Variable Solution 3

```
class SamMethod:
    def __init__(self, func, arg):
        self.func = func
        self.arg = arg

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(self.arg, *args, **kwargs)

class Descriptor:
    def __get__(descriptor, self, cls):
        lamby = object.__getattribute__
        if self: # self != None
            lamby = SamMethod(object.__getattribute__, self)
        return lamby

class K:
    __getattribute__ = Descriptor()
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

#### Final remarks on the problem of global variables

Solution **2** has a problem in that the signature of the `method` class constructor might change in a future version of python. Solution **3** is my favorite, but feel free to pick your own.

### Inheritance

Inheritance works just fine:

```
class SamMethod:
def __init__(self, func, arg):
    self.func = func
    self.arg = arg

def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.func(self.arg, *args, **kwargs)

#############################################################################

class Descriptor:
    def __get__(descriptor, self, cls):
        print(
            "MESSAGE"
        )
        lamby = object.__getattribute__
        if self:  # self != None
            lamby = SamMethod(object.__getattribute__, self)
        return lamby

###############################################################################

class ParentOfKlaus:
    __getattribute__  = Descriptor()

class Klaus(ParentOfKlaus):
    def foo(self):
        print("Klaus.foo")

class ChildOfKlaus(Klaus):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 99

    def foo(self):
        print("ChildOfKlaus.foo")

instance = ChildOfKlaus()
y = instance.x
print(y) # 99
instance.foo()
```

The console output is:

```
MESSAGE
99
MESSAGE
ChildOfKlaus.foo
```

### Why make `__getattribute__`  a descriptor instead of overriding `__getattribute__`?

One advantage is that we have access to the class parameter passed into descriptor `__get__` methods. Note that `__get__` is called as `__get__(descriptor, Kinstance, Kclass)` We don't normally have direct access to `Kclass`, but if `__getattribute__` is written as a descriptor, then it can access `Kclass`

Comment: I do not understand the second half of this answer, `self` is not a global variable, and I'm not sure what you are trying to avoid. You seem to be talking about lexical scoping of the *free variable* `self` in lamby, but again, I'm not sure why that is a problem. The normal solution to that is to bind it by using a higher order function, so `return lambda self_: object.__getattribute__(self_, attrname)(self)`. Overall, you are essentially re-inventing the function descriptor behavior, but again, I'm not sure why, because you can always access the class using `type(self)`.

Comment: The class parameter is just `type(instance)` anyway when invoking a descriptor on an instance. It exists for the class case, where `cls.descriptor_managed_attribute` calls `descriptor.__get__(None, cls)`.

Comment: From this answer, it looks like you're entirely unaware of the concept of *closure variables*. You should read about them; it might clear up some of the misunderstandings behind all those "avoiding global variables" questions you've been posting recently across this account and [your alt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12119282/samuel-muldoon).